# How to match a specified character after the nth occurrence of a delimiter

Tags: regex, string

I just tested a regex on regex101 and getting a somewhat unexpected results. The expression I tried is

`^[^-]*(?:-[^-]*){1}\Kt`

on this string

`this is a test - try to split -this- string - into its substrings`

the matching result on regex101 is the "t" at the end of the word "split"

> this is a test - try to spli**t** -this- string - into its substrings

why didn't it return the first "t" in the word "try"?

> this is a test - **t**ry to split -this- string - into its substrings

Comment: Because `*` is greedy and `[^-]` matches `t`. Did you intend to use [`^[^-]*-[^-]*?\Kt`](https://regex101.com/r/f4GnKU/1)? Or even `^[^-]*-[^-t]*\Kt`?

Comment: wow, thanks, that definitely worked. You are awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things here to note:

- The `[^-]` matches `t`, and with the `*` greedy quantifier it matches up to the last `t` it finds on its way
- The `t` can be added to the negated character class to match up to the first `t, or make`*`lazy with`*?`
- `{1}` limiting quantifier is redundant since each pattern atom matches once by default
- There is no point using a non-capturing group for only one branch in it or without a quantifier

Use

```
^[^-]*-[^-]*?\Kt
```

or

```
^[^-]*-[^-t]*\Kt
```

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Just curious, without specifying the non-capturing group and the subsequent numbered quantifier, how would I select the "t" in the word "string" (i.e. after 3 occurrences of the "-" delimiter), using the previous expression with non-capturing group, that can be achieved with ^[^-]*(?:-[^-]*?){3}\Kt

Comment: Then you need to use a grouping construct. I wrote:  *for only one branch in it **or without a quantifier***. If you need to use a quantifier, you must use a group.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I only started out on regex 2-3 hours ago, so that one branch part is a bit cryptic to me so I got confused and skimped the next part, sorry.

Comment: Ok, I see. If you need more clarifications here, feel free to drop a comment.